# macOS 10.15.6, is there a way to get an early low battery warning?

Tags: battery, notifications

I usually only get the low battery warning when I'm at 1% or so. How do I make it so the notification pops up at 5%, 10%, 20%, etc. Preferably all of those.

Comment: Not sure if there’s system notifications for that, but I use a little app called Unplugged from the App Store which pushes notifications at every 10% intervals and every 5% intervals below 20%. Might be worth a try?

Comment: What model of Mac? I'm pretty sure that I get warnings at those numbers, without having set anything, on my 2014 MBP.

Comment: I have a 2018 MBP, and I only ever get a 1%. It's pretty irritating and frustrating cause I have to drop everything and go grab a charger.